# how to navigate a nested loop

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-loops

I am new to python and I've been trying to wrap my head around this code:

```
stop = int(input())
result = 0
for a in range(4):
    print(a, end=': ')
    for b in range(2):
        result += a + b
        if result > stop:
            print('-', end=' ')
            continue
        print(result, end=' ')
    print()
```

When I input `6`, the output is

```
0: 0 1 
1: 2 4 
2: 6 - 
3: - -
```

why isn't it

```
0: 0 1
1: 3 4 --> since we're starting out with a = 1 and b = 2 so result is 1 + 2 = 3.
etc
```

I feel like I'm missing something fundamental.

Comment: `b` always starts at 0. For the first number in line 1, the old `result` is 1, `a` is 1, and `b` is 0, so you get a new `result` of 2.

Comment: You could try to run in this great platform - https://pythontutor.com/ to *debug* and see what's happening each step next time.

Answer (score 3):

Value of b will never be 2.
Each iteration of loop will initialise the scope variables. i.e. while looping first loop, value of b will range between 0 & 1.

Whereas, Value of result (a global variable) will be cumulative (value obtained from prev iteration).

| iteration | a | b | result | output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0: 0.. |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0: 0 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 1: 2.. |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 1: 2 4 |
| 5 | 2 | 0 | 6 | 2: 6.. |
| 6 | 2 | 1 | 9 | 2: 6 9 |
| 7 | 3 | 0 | 12 | 3: 12.. |
| 8 | 3 | 1 | 16 | 3: 12 16 |

Comment: the table is super helpful, thank you! i just realised that i've been overlooking the changing result value over the course of the iteration too. D: thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
when a = 0 and b = 1,  result = 0 + 0 + 1 = 1, 

so, for a = 1 and b = 0, result = 1 + 1 + 0 = 2
when a = 1 and b = 1, result = 2 + 1 + 1 = 4

so, it will print 1: 2 4
```